# Select specific Fields to output to CSV - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I have a database from which i have to export to a csv/text file the `longtitude` and `lantitude` in this form:

```
25.767368,-80.18930
34.088808,-118.40612
40.727093,-73.97864

# Lat,Long
```

The attributes in my database are in a correct format and i only need the export. As my knowledge of working straight with Databases is limited [i only got to this point](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY (Select * From users) To '/Users/tmj/Desktop/text.csv' With CSV;
```

Which just dumps the entire database in a csv..

How can i select the 2 attributes i need and have them outputted in the correct format (lat,long)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COPY (Select latitude,longitude From users) To '/Users/tmj/Desktop/text.csv' With CSV;
```

Comment: Hm, i tried that before, but it throws an `column "longtitude" does not exist`. The attributes are exactly => `longtitude` and `latitude`

Comment: I am just guessing the the column names here. Can you list them, using something like this: select column_name from information_schema.columns where
table_name='users'

Comment: longtitude is the incorrect spelling. it should be longitude - is that the issue you are having??

Comment: Jesus.. Indeed that was the problem... Thanks a lot :)